# Importing procedures in MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if there was a way to write the code of a SQL procedure in a file .sql (or at least I think it should be .sql) and then import that procedure in my database (importing the file .sql). I would like to write the code in a separated file using an IDE like Geany because it is visually more confortable for me. 
I already searched through Google but I only found ways to import (and export) in phpmyadmin, but I don't even know what it is. I am typing the code of my procedures using the terminal line, but I'd like to do this in some other ways.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: If the only tool you are using to interact with your mysql database as a developer is the command line then I highly suggest you look into a tool such as MySQL Workbench, or any of a number of such tools that are available.

Comment: The fact is that I am studying databases and my teacher wants us to do it all using basic MySQL. So I have to type everything in the command line, but maybe I could write the code of procedures in separated files and then import that code in MySQL using a specific command (if it exists, obviously).

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL Workbench.

https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

It's easy - clean interface.

There is also HeidSQL (https://www.heidisql.com/) and a whole lot of others.

Personally I prefer MySQL Workbench.